# Python date string to apache-like date format

Tags: python, datetime

Simple question. I have a string formatted as follows:

```
2012-04-30 23:59:01 EDT
```

I would like to convert it to an apache log conforming date format:

```
[30/Apr/2012:23:59:01 +0300]
```

I was quite sure the following code (which uses *datetime*) would work:

```
time0 = '2012-04-30 23:59:01 EDT'
time1 = datetime.strptime(time0,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
time2 = datetime.strftime(time1,'[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]')
```

But if I print the three variables above, the content of **time1** and **time2** are not as expected. More specifically, the **EDT** doesn't seem to be parsed correctly.

```
time0 = 2012-04-30 23:59:01 EDT
time1 = 2012-04-30 23:59:01
time2 = [30/Apr/2012:23:59:01 ]
```

Comment: The docs have a caveat: For a naive object, the `%z` and `%Z` format codes are replaced by empty strings.  You need to make it an "aware" object (I don't quite know how)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `datetime` (especially `strptime`) is somewhat notorious for being bad at time zones. You generally need to load in time zone info with another library like `pytz` or something similar.

If you can, use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for date parsing. It's far easier in my opinion and has all of the time zones and DST stuff built in.

```
from dateutil import parser
time1 = parser.parse('2012-04-30 23:59:01 EDT', tzinfos={'EDT' : +18000})
datetime.strftime(time1,'[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]')
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `tzinfos={'EDT': -14400}` or `tzinfos={'EDT': +39600}`?

Comment: This is great and your code seems to work for me! J.F. might be right about the timezone detail but in any case, this solution did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` objects can be described as either "naive" or "aware", referring to their awareness of time zone information. In order to make a `datetime` object aware, you need to supply it with a `tzinfo` object. You're not doing so here, so you are using naive `datetime`s. According to the [datetime documentation on strftime/strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> For a naive object, the %z and %Z format codes are replaced by empty
>   strings.

Edit: Looking into the documentation a bit further, it appears that `strptime` drops time zone information altogether, so you'll have to use a different method, such as the `dateutil` module suggested elsewhere.